# ,Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,Non HTTP response message: Host may not be blank,

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a script in cloud with url and port parametrized to read from property file. It is observed that for the first 10 request I get below error with url null while rest of test goes smoothly without issues

Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,Non HTTP response message: Host may not be blank,Test failed: text expected to contain /Search Results/,1,9,null,,1,1

I am unable to figure it out the problem. Can you kindly suggest

Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: And I also dont know why the blank line in the report is coming with throughput infinity. I dont have any transactions in the script without label. I am guessing its something to do with my corrupted request

Comment: Can you show your HTTP Request in jmeter test plan ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you either:

- didn't pass a property to your test using:

> -JAppURIVal=hostname

- Or you passed an URL instead of a host name

> -JAppURIVal=http://hostname should be -JAppURIVal=hostname

Comment: ok, I will try. the behaviour is observed only for 10 request, rest all good. You think there might be a delay due to which property file containing the host name and port wasn't able to read  by jmeter?

Comment: No in this case it is strange. Can you show jmeter.log and more about your test plan ?Thanks